# What is the expression for $|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|$ if $|\psi\rangle=\cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle+\sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi}|1\rangle$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

Let $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$. In Bloch sphere representation, this is
$\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}|1\rangle$.

In matrix representation:

> $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = \cos^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle\langle0| + \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}|0\rangle\langle 1| + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}|1\rangle\langle0| + \sin^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}e^{2i\phi}|1\rangle\langle 1|\,.$

However, I am told it is also equivalent to restate the above as

> $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = \cos^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle\langle0| + \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-i\phi}|0\rangle\langle 1| + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}cos\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}|1\rangle\langle0| + \sin^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle\langle 1|\,.$

Note the difference in the (0,1) and (1,1) entry.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the fact that
$$ \langle \psi | = \bigg( |\psi\rangle \bigg)^{\dagger} \,.$$

"$\langle \psi|$" is conjugate transpose of "$|\psi\rangle$".

So, if

$$|\psi\rangle = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}|1\rangle\,,$$

then

$$\langle \psi| = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\langle 0| + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-i\phi}\langle 1 |\,.$$

Since $e^{i \phi}$ is a complex number, it will gain a negative sign in the exponent.

So now, if you calculate $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, you will get the second equation, which is the correct one.

Comment: thank you for the spot